# Send object to controller through ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I have to send an object from view page to controller.

Ajax code:--

```
var jsdata = '{p:' + data + '}';
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: rootURL + "Deal/Check",
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  data:JSON.stringify(jsdata, null, 2) ,
  success: function (data) {}
  });
```

Controller:-

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Check(DealCreateViewModel p)
{      
  CheckAvailabilities(p);
  return View();
}
```

DealCreateViewModel :--

```
public List<AllocationID> Titles { get; set; }
public List<AllocationID> Episodes { get; set; }
[UIHint("MultiPicker")] public List<AllocationID> Assets { get; set; }
[UIHint("MultiPicker")] public List<QuickID> Documents { get; set; }
[UIHint("MultiPicker")] public List<AllocationID> Languages { get; set; }
[UIHint("MultiPicker")] public List<AllocationID> Territories { get; set; }
[UIHint("MultiPicker")] public List<AllocationID> Countries { get; set; }
[UIHint("MultiPicker")] public List<AllocationID> Rights { get; set; }
[UIHint("MultiPicker")] public List<AllocationID> Contributors { get; set; }
[UIHint("MultiPicker")] public List<AllocationID> Transmissions { get; set; }
```

The object "data" which I am sending through ajax can be anything means it can be either list of assets,list of titles,list of episodes or anything else from Viewmodel.

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: Actully using this code which I posted I am not able to get object in controller.Even if ajax call the Check Action of controller but its not posting data to this action.

Comment: Have the action accept a json string instead?!

Comment: No its not posting string even.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
     $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: rootURL + "Deal/Check",
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType:'json',
  data: { p : data }, 
  success: function (data) {}
  });
```

Comment: This code is not even calling the action.Its throwing following error--Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: btw what is rootURL here @AkankshaT

Comment: Its just for the path where the data will be posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can send it as a simple json string. However, you won't know the type of object or the class of object. So we must specify the type along with the json string we pass to the action method. In your case, you need to specify a **list type** (AllocationID, QuickID), and an **object class** (Document, Location, etc).

Hence sample json would look like:

```
var jsdata = {
    "listType": "AllocationID",
    "objectName" : "Documents",
    "data": [
            //list of json object representing a document.
        ]
    };

var dto = { jsonData: jsData };
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: rootURL + "Deal/Check",
  data:JSON.stringify(dto),
  success: function (data) {}
  });
```

Your action method will look like:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<ActionResult> Check(string jsonData)
 {
    //use newtonsoft json parser
    JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
    var listType = obj["listType"].Value<string>();
    if(listType == 'AllocationID')
    {
         var jarr = obj["data"].Value<JArray>();
         List<AllocationID> documents = jarr.ToObject<List<AllocationID>>();
         //do something with documents list...
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you share what you are observing?

Comment: You should remove the contentType from the $.ajax call. Edited the answer.